FRRouting BGP Not Routing After Assigning IP to WAN Interface
I'm having trouble with a BGP setup using FRRouting to handle internal load balancing, and I'm hoping someone here can help! Here's the basic structure (the WAN connection is via eth9 on the router):
[Internet] ---> [Router (FRRouting)] ---> [Multiple nodes announcing they can route 123.0.2.108/32]
FRRouting correctly adds a route for 123.0.2.108/32 to the router's routing table (after receiving routes) and I can ping 123.0.2.108 from the router. However, I hit a snag when I assign 123.0.2.108 to the WAN interface of the router using the command:
ip addr add 123.0.2.108/32 dev eth9
At this point, FRRouting stops routing 123.0.2.108/32 via BGP, and it looks like the kernel takes over instead. When I run show ip route in vtysh, The route changes from B> (BGP) to C (connected) meaning FRRouting is no longer handling the route at all.
If I don't use ip addr add, then the router doesn't respond to ARP queries for 123.0.2.108, and the upstream router doesn't forward traffic correctly.
I can mitigate the issue by enabling proxy_arp but I'm aware thats not an optimal solution.
Thanks for any help in advance!

Can you post a sanitized config of your interface and bgp setup? Also, is .108 supposed to be your own router or the far end of the eth9 link?
